# ¿Cómo buscar posición en objetos?

Tags: javascript

Por ejemplo la posición dónde está la string `"4"`

```
objeto1 = { '4': 1, '5': 1, '9': 1 }
objeto2 = { '4': 2, '8': 1, '9': 2 }

objeto1.indexOf("4"); // da error
objeto2.indexOf("4"); // da error
```

Intento hacer una función que haga:

En el `objeto1` busca el string "4", en el `objeto2` busca el string "4".

Una vez localizada esa posición, compara a ver si ambas posiciones tienen el mismo "valor". El `objeto1` en esa posición tiene `1`, y el `objeto2` en esa posición tiene `2`

Comment: **objeto2**.indexOf("4"); es **objeto2** la 4ta linea???

Comment: perdón si, ahora lo edito que me confundí

Comment: Tus JSON´s no son array, son objetos, con lo cual indexof, no existe.

Comment: con solo hacer `!!objeto1['4']` sabes si existe la propiedad de ese Objeto,cuando es objeto no existe posicion, si tu arreglo es algo como `[{a: 1}, {a:2}]` es distinto, si quieres buscar tienes que hacer algo como `const a =Objects.keys(objeto); a.indexOf('4')`

Comment: Sólo por aclarar las cosas: lo que tu llamas string es realmente la *clave* o nombre de la propiedad. Por lo que entiendo por la pregunta y la respuesta aceptada, lo que quieres saber es *cómo comprobar si un objeto tiene una propiedad*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto podría ser la respuesta???

```js
objeto1 = { '4': 1, '5': 1, '9': 1 }
objeto2 = { '4': 2, '8': 1, '9': 2 }

if (objeto1["4"] == objeto2["4"])
  console.log("son iguales");
else
  console.log("son distintos");
```

Comment: Para no confundir, esto no toma el index, ya que no existe en este objeto, sino que aplica el uso de brackets notation, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: Toda la razón, falto detaller la respuesta, muchas gracias por el enlace.

Comment: primero preguntaria  [si existe la propiedad en ambos objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/hasOwnProperty) y luego comparo

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción puede ser usando [Lodash](https://lodash.com/).

La funcion [_.has](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#has) o bien [_hasIn](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#hasIn), de esta forma compruebas de que exista y que además este presente en ambos objetos.

```js
objeto1 = { '4': 1, '5': 1, '9': 1 }
objeto2 = { '4': 2, '8': 1, '9': 2 }

if(_.has(objeto1, 4) && _.has(objeto2, 4)){
  console.log('encontrado')
} else {
  console.log('no encontrado')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```